Aws lightsail wordpress instance default user credentials?
I am building a automated system to configure lightsail wordpress instances with static ip addresses using the lambda function. I have two approaches either of these will work for me.
1- Is it possible to configure the administrator user credentials while configuration?
2- How to get the default application password while configuration in lambda automatically.|
This is the code I am using for lightsail wordpress instance configuration.
`module.exports.createLightsailInstance = async (event) => {
try {
const instanceNames = JSON.parse(event?.body).instanceNames;
    const instanceCreationPromises = instanceNames.map(async (instanceName) => {

        // Create a Lightsail instance
        const createInstanceParams = {
            instanceNames: [instanceName],
            blueprintId: 'wordpress',
            bundleId: 'nano_3_0',
            availabilityZone: 'ap-northeast-1a',
            tags: [
                {
                    key: 'Name',
                    value: instanceName
                }
            ],
        };

        const createInstanceResponse = await lightsail.createInstances(createInstanceParams).promise();
        return createInstanceResponse;
    });

    await Promise.all(instanceCreationPromises);

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            message: 'Lightsail instances are successfully created. You can run them in few minutes.',
            data: createInstanceResponse,
        })
    };
} catch (error) {
     return {
        statusCode: 500,
        body: JSON.stringify({
           message: 'Failed to create Lightsail instances.'
        })
     };
}

};
`
I have tried to SSM but it is not working for me.
